# Trouble pushing to stack Java

Tags: java, stack, push

Having some issues trying to push to stack, whenever I push one of these queues to the stack it seems to override the previous queue that I just pushed to the stack. The top number updates though?

Like if I go to print it out it will print out the most recent queue I pushed then then it errors trying to print any more because there's nothing stored in the lower array values.

Here's the code I'm using to push the queues

```
        Stack countryStack = new Stack(200);
        while(!firstPriority.isEmpty()){
            countryStack.push(firstPriority.remove());
        }
        while(!secondPriority.isEmpty()){
            countryStack.push(secondPriority.remove());
        }
```

Here's the code I'm using to construct the stack and push to the stack

```
    private int maxSize;
    private Country[] stackArray;
    private int top;

    public Stack(int s){
        maxSize = s;
        stackArray = new Country[maxSize];
        top =-1;
    }

    public void push(Country newCountry){
        if(isFull()){
            System.out.println("The Stack is full");
        }else {
            stackArray[++top] = newCountry;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `pop()`?

Comment: There’s not enough information here to help.

Comment: Java has a builtin `Stack` that is likely preferable to rolling your own. Please share a [mcve] for help here.

Comment: @ggorlen I'm pretty sure this is homework/exercise. Using the standard library's class would render it moot.

Comment: Probably, but since it's not actually stated, that's an assumption. Even if it was, OP should still know that better ways to do things exist.

Comment: @ggorlen And the OP likely does, or will. This is clearly a learning exercise (and a good one; data structures are important).